# EF query sometimes gives result set from different schemas

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework-6

Im working on a legacy application that uses Entity framework in a C# REST API. It uses óne postgresql database with óne schema for authentication and every organization has their own schema. Sometimes in production we get reports about people seeing data from a whole other schema and sometimes partly their own partly from another organization.

Excuse me in advance for grammar mistakes.

The application uses óne postgresql database with óne schema for authentication and every organization has their own schema.

### test_database

- Authentication_schema
- orgschema_x
- orgschema_y
- orgschema_z

The dbcontext for the organization schemas constructor requires an argument which is the users organization from another context which in our example could be x.

The entity framework EDMX is generated based upon database first from the first organization (all organizations have the same structure), and uses an implementation of System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.IDbCommandInterceptor called Replace Schema Interceptor to modify the schema name and therefore modify the queries sent to the database before they are actually sent.

Every CRUD request makes its own context based on the user, and will close connections after a call.

Its always the same user that encounters this issue and for us developer we never have been able to reproduce this issue, we know it is an issue though because we've seen in the logs that the user wrote data in another schema.

- We've already tried to log the queries to make sure the replaceschemainterceptor does its job, and it does. We got a report and screenshot of wrong data while there is nothing to be found in the logs.
- We've already changed every method to make sure they are making a new dbcontext every time it gets called.
- We disabled proxycreation and lazyloading.

We're out of ideas currently as we can't reproduce it and the specific user has it only 1 out of 100 times.

DBContext initialization and simple request

```
using (var context = new dbEntities("orgschema_" + db.Organization))
{
      /** Any code from lists to single objects possible here */

      table1 data = context.table1.Where(x => x.name == testname).FirstOrDefault();
      return data;
}
```

The organization of the user is already set on logging in.

The specific replaceschemainterception method. Which finds all orgschema_ and replaces the organization behind it.

```
private String ReplaceSchema(String sql)
{
 int index = sql.IndexOf("orgschema_");
 if (index == -1)
 {
  return sql;
 }
 String userStart = sql.Substring(index);

 int endIndex = userStart.IndexOf("\"");
 if (endIndex == -1)
 endIndex = userStart.IndexOf(".");

 String user = sql.Substring(index, endIndex);
 sql = sql.Replace(user, _newSchema);
 return sql;
}
```

In the dbContext constructor the following code is executed.

```
public dbEntities(string sConnectionString) : base("name=dbEntities") 
{
         System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbInterception.Add(new 
         ReplaceSchemaInterceptor(newSchema: sConnectionString));
}
```

I expect the API to always return the data from the correct organization. But it does not 100/100 times and we cannot reproduce it. Is there anyone who has experienced something similair and can push us into the right direction?

For any needed additional information feel free to ask! :)

Comment: What happens in `dbEntities`'s constructor? Also, it's schema, not scheme.

Comment: @GertArnold Thanks for the response, it just adds the SchemaInterceptor, see original post. And thanks for the grammatical correction :).

Comment: I think your first line of defence should be the database: let users have access to their own schema only. Then in the application layer you could store a compiled model per tenant, either permanently or in-memory. This is because the schema is part of the model and normally EF (6) only stores one compiled model per app domain. Then you don't need this somewhat wobbly text manipulation.